# A probability; definition.

Tags: number-theory, statistics

According to my prof, he says the "probability" is defined as a function from the sample space $S$ to the $[0,1]$ such that the three axioms of probability hold.

I want to make a correction that it is actually to the set $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ because technically $1/\pi$ is not a real probability.

My question is: Why are we allowed to have irrational probabilities? When irrational numbers themselves don't exist in real life

Comment: so, where is the question?

Comment: What's wrong with $\frac{1}{\pi}$? If I pick a point from $[0, 1]$ at random, what is the probability that it is less than $\frac{1}{\pi}$? The answer is $\frac{1}{\pi}$.

Comment: But I was just thinking that in a real life situation. How can the denominator be $\pi$? It's saying the total possible outcomes is $\pi$

Comment: There's no such thing as probability in real life. Probability is in our minds, not in reality. Probability is part of map, not part of the territory.

Comment: @sidht:Not necessarrily, that's just assuming that all outcomes are equally likely. For example you could make a coin that weighted so that heads comes up $\frac{2}{3}$ of the time. If you are ok with this, why does it seem weird to be able to make a coin such that heads come up $\frac{1}{\pi}$ of the time.

Comment: Whether or not real life is rational, a probabilistic model is a *mathematical model* that fits mostly only modestly well. Restricting to the rationals would have disastrous technical consequences because of countable additivity.

Comment: But you can't get $\pi$ probabilities. It's not possible to construct a weighted coin that can yield heads $1/\pi$ times.

Comment: "It's not possible to construct a weighted coin that can yield heads 1/π times." Why do you think more difficult to build a weighted coin yielding heads 1/π times than one yielding heads half of the times? The answer to that seems to be at the heart of your trouble.

Comment: Think of the circle centre origin, radius $1$. Pick a point $P$ at random on the circle (uniform distribution). What is the probability the distance from $P$ to $(1,0)$ is $\le 1/2$? You will find it is irrational.

Comment: @Did, because it is hard to "count" $\pi$ *exactly*

Comment: @sidht Define "count $\pi$".

Comment: @Did, I can't because it is impossible to count all the digits of $\pi$. Irrationals don't exist in real life

Comment: "Irrationals don't exist in real life"... Probably untrue with the meaning you give to the phrase. Here is an experiment: throw darts at a disk of radius $1$, say centered at $(0,0)$. Divide the number of darts landing in the square with vertices $(\pm1,0)$ and $(0,\pm1)$ by the number of darts landing in the disk. Then this proportion goes to $1/\pi$. Difficult to make it more "real life", eh?

Comment: No number exists in real life.  Do $\sqrt 2$ and $\pi$ really have no meaning for you?

Comment: Okay, I think i got it now. I tried out Andre's example, but the integration got a bit complicated and I felt that the $\pi$ would have still cancelled. Did's example convinced me that I can't take this probability stuff too seriously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is incorrect that a probability is a function on $S$.  A probability is a function whose domain is a certain collection(*) $\Sigma$ of *subsets* of $S$ and whose range is contained in [0, 1].  As noted, this function must satisfy the axioms that were presented to you.  As others have noted in comments, the range need not (and in general does not) consist only of rationals.  For example, let $S = [-1, 1] \times [-1, 1]$ and let $PA =$ (the area of $A$)/4.  Then $P\{(x,y):x^2 + y^2 < 1\} = \pi/4$.

(*) $\Sigma$ must contain $S$ and be closed under countable union and complementation.  This is called a $\sigma$-field.  First courses in applied probability usually do not mention this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll see later on that there will be probabilities in exponential form, which can't actually be written as a sum of elements of $\mathbb{Q}$. You can look up exponential distribution online if you want. So indeed, there will be cases wherein the probability is not rational.

Comment: Oh, like the Poison!? But isn't the Poison just an approximation for large samples? But large enough doesn't imply infinity since reaching infinity is impossible

Comment: @sidht I think you mean Poisson.